# Request timeout error while processing long tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have an c# asp.net management system with a button that calls a SQL Server Query to get 90,000 strings of text in multiple languages and categorized into sections.  This in turn is sorted and 150 Binary files made before saving as a .ZIP and emailing the user with the results.  The total time to process this and email the results is about 6 minutes.  In this time the Web Page is sat waiting for the whole process to complete.  I would like to be able to press the start process button and then allow this to work away in the background while I continue using the web management system, but I am unsure what is the most efficient method for doing this.  I initially created an asmx file thinking this would work but the result is the same and so I am now looking at async and await.  Can anyone give me any pointers on this and let me know if I am on the right track.  I am currently not getting anything back to let me know the process has completed successfully as I can handle this by emailing the user to say something went wrong.  The reason for this is the user could be on any number of pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to go about tackling this problem. Your options will vary based on what version of .NET you are using, so I'll not post code directly; however, the you can implement the concept I describe using ASMX web services, WCF, MVC, and so on.

**Start-and-poll Approach**

The classic response for this kind of problem is to implement a `StartSomething()` method and a `GetProgress()` method. A very-simple example of this approach using ASMX-based web services [is presented here](http://blog.robseder.com/2013/10/18/executing-a-long-running-process-from-a-web-page/).

In the example, one service method is used to start a process on a background thread. Myself, I would change the example by having the start method return a value to the client to identify *which* background process was started, as you could feasibly have several going on at a time.

The client then can call a separate method to get progress updates, and continue polling until the process is complete.

There are a number of reasons [why you should prefer to do lengthy background processing in a non-IIS service](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). I recommend using a Windows service to protect yourself from IIS somewhat-randomly restarting your application pool in the middle of a big job.

**WebSockets**

Another option worth some exploration on your part is to use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which allow the server to contact a modern browser when the process is complete. The main advantage of this approach is that the client does not need to busily poll the service for updates. Its primary disadvantage is that WebSockets are new enough that there are still plenty of browsers that could not be clients for such a service.

Good luck!